# How to Pass Parameters to Action Method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, actionmethod

I have a controller `DPN` and within that controller, I have an Action Method

```
[HttpGet]
public virtual ActionResult Report(string reportName)
{
   str_ReportPath = string.IsNullOrEmpty(str_ReportPath) ? "/BundleDealer/" + reportName : str_ReportPath;
   return View();
}
```

I want to know how can I pass a parameter to `Report` using `Url.Action`
I tried this but got an error

```
<a href="@Url.Action(MVC.DPN.Report(), "AffiliateTFNDailySummary")">Provider</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Report", "controller name", new { reportName = "AffiliateTFNDailySummary" })">Provider</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Url.Action("Report", "ControllerName", new { reportName = "AffiliateTFNDailySummary"});
```